# How do I use a different node template on taxonomy term node listing pages?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

For a node listing on a taxonomy term page, like:

> taxonomy/term/4

It's currently using the node template I set up just for when you are looking at a node:

> node--spot.tpl.php

I added this code to hook_preprocess_node:

```
if(arg(0) == 'taxonomy') {
  array_push($vars['theme_hook_suggestions'], 'node_taxonomy');
}
```

The node template file name I want to use is:

> node-taxonomy.tpl.php

I confirmed the hook is running but it's still using:

> node--spot.tpl.php

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1**: According to the source code theme_hook_suggestions are listed in reverse priority order, so I changed array_unshift to array_push.

**Update 2**: I am correctly seeing in Devel themer that my template should be used first, even when it isn't:

> node_taxonomy < node_*14 < node*_spot < sites/all/themes/hotness/templates/node--spot.tpl.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer had two parts:

1. As detailed in my Update #1, you have to put your suggestion last in the theme_hook_suggestions array, as last is highest priority.
2. Your template files must be named with two dashes, not one.

File system:

> node--taxonomy.tpl.php

As added to theme_hook_suggestions array:

> node__taxonomy

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions']` in hook_preprocess_node, `$vars` is in hook_preprocess_page I guess.

Comment: It is totally up to you how do you want to name the variable `$variables` oder `$vars`, it doesn't matter.